# Force-evaluate function argument in order to "trick" substitute()?

Tags: r, nse

say I have a function from an R package which I want to wrap in a closure for convenience and better code readability. For simplicity, let's assume the function looks as follows:

```r
fun <- function(text) {
    as.character(substitute(text))
}
```

When I call that function from the console, e.g.

```r
fun(text = "bar")
```

the returned value is `"bar"`, which in my case is the desired behavior. The reason the function is written the way it is, is that in case I call

```r
fun(text = bar)
```

the output is also `"bar"`. Just for context. I obviously didn't write this function by myself, I just want to use it.

**The problem:** When I call `fun` from within a function, like e.g.

```r
fun2 <- function(foo) {
    fun(text = foo)
}
fun2(foo = "bar")
```

the output will always be `"foo"` instead of "bar", regardless of what I assign to `foo` in the call to `fun2`. Ofc I know this is how `substitute()` is intended to work, but this makes it impossible (or at least very nasty?), to programmatically work with the function `fun`.

**My Question:** Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior without rewriting `fun`?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct the call inside `fun2` and evaluate it:

```r
fun2 <- function(foo) {
  eval(call("fun", foo))
}

fun2(foo = "bar")
#> [1] "bar"
```

The problem here is that it now no longer works if you pass `bar` unquoted:

```r
fun2(foo = bar)
#> Error in eval(call("fun", foo)) : object 'bar' not found
```

So you would need something like:

```r
fun2 <- function(foo) {
  if(exists(as.character(substitute(foo)), parent.frame())) {
    eval(call("fun", foo))
  } else {
    eval(call("fun", as.character(substitute(foo))))
  }
}
```

Which now works either way:

```r
fun2(foo = "bar")
#> [1] "bar"

fun2(foo = bar)
#> [1] "bar"
```

The problem here is that if `bar` actually exists, then it will be interpreted as *the value* of `bar`, so we have:

```r
fun2(foo = "bar")
#> [1] "bar"

fun2(foo = bar)
#> [1] "bar"

bar <- 1

fun2(foo = bar)
#> [1] "1"
```

Which is presumably not what you intended.

However, if you were going to do it this way, it probably no longer makes sense to call `fun` at all. Perhaps the easiest thing to do is

```r
fun2 <- function(foo) {
  as.character(match.call()$foo)
}

fun2("bar")
#> [1] "bar"

fun2(bar)
#> [1] "bar"

bar <- 1

fun2(bar)
#> [1] "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, that wasn't as hard as I thought. Actually your very first solution already does it for me, since I do not care whether `fun2(bar)` returns the same as `fun2("bar")`. For my use case, being able to use `fun2("bar")` is perfectly fine :)